# Use gridview and listview in same activity and make the whole screen scrollable

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I am working on a concept to make gridview and listview in a same activity and want to make whole screen scrollable.

My concept is :

I have created a listview **A** as main listview and adding gridview  **g** and another listview **l** as header and footer of main listview **A** but this is not making the whole screen scrollable.

**Here is my main xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shopping_list_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dark_pink_header"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_but" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/devicder_button"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back_button"
            android:background="@drawable/divider" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sample_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/devicder_button"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_icon" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mid_header_rl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fav_button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sample_button"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logoIMg"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/store_guide_logo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logoIMg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/e_couponing"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/fav_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_favorite_checkbox"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/estickermainListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativelayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Footer xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/estickertListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Header xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_rl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/esticker_txt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/e_stickers_list"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/e_sticker_gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/quantiy_product_rl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shopping_list_top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coupon_bonanza_Txt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/coupon_bonanza"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```